# I'm having trouble using XMLAGG and getting ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table in oracle and working in SQL Developer and I'm trying to get all the rows in a xml string but when I try to do it in a single line with XMLAGG I get an exception 
ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified.

```
+------------------+
| empleados        |
+------------------+
| nomina | empresa |
+--------+---------+
| 212121 | 31      |
+--------+---------+
| 212122 | 32      |
+--------+---------+
| 212123 | 33      |
+--------+---------+
```

This is for a Oracle 11 DB

Try 1
    SELECT 
    XMLElement("employees", XMLAgg
                           (XMLElement("Employee",e.nomina||' '||e.empresa)ORDER BY 
                             e.nomina
    ))
     AS "Dept_list"     
     FROM empleados e;

Try 2

```
SELECT XMLROOT(
        XMLELEMENT("employees",
          XMLAGG(
            XMLELEMENT("employee",
              XMLFOREST(
                e.nomina AS "nomina",
                e.empresa AS "empresa")
            )
          )
        )
      ) 
      AS employees
FROM   empleados e;
```

I expect a string like

```
<employees>
   <employee>
      <nomina>212121</nomina>
      <empresa>21</empresa>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <nomina>212122</nomina>
      <empresa>22</empresa>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <nomina>212123</nomina>
      <empresa>23</empresa>
   </employee>
</employees>
```

But I keep getting

```
ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In try 2  you have to add one more parameter to xmlroot( xmltype,  version 1). 
Probably main problem is in "sql developer". Missing java libs or crazy transformation of xmltype.

Try this

```
xmlserialize(document
        XMLELEMENT("employees",
          XMLAGG(
            XMLELEMENT("employee",
              XMLFOREST(
                e.object_id AS "nomina",
                e.object_type AS "empresa")
            )
          )
        )
     as clob indent size = 2)
      AS employees ...
```

or as varchar

```
xmlserialize(document
        XMLELEMENT("employees",
          XMLAGG(
            XMLELEMENT("employee",
              XMLFOREST(
                e.object_id AS "nomina",
                e.object_type AS "empresa")
            )
          )
        )
     as varchar2(4000) indent size = 2)
      AS employees ...
```